# Программирование под IOS, Android.

Tags: android, ios

Возник вопрос, что лучше. Учить Objective-C и Java. Или же учить C# и пользоваться дополнениями типа Xamarin. Ну или учить AS. Для программирования под IOS и Android.

Answer (score 2):

Имхо, серьёзно следует разобраться в чем-то одном, причем нативном. В таком случае вы постигните платформу всеобъемлюще, без ограничений, накладываемых кроссплатформенностью( как в том же Xamarin ). В вашем случае следует выбрать что-то одно: либо IOS, либо Android. Хорошенько изучить. В процессе уже можно задумываться о кроссплатформенных мобильных технологиях.

Comment: Ну, а AS например

Comment: что за "AS"?

Answer (score 0):

Ранее тоже задавался этим вопросом, как я ни пытался использовать Xamarin - все бесполезно. Лучше сразу начинать осваивать Java под Андроид. Есть некоторые различия от Джавы (Явы), конечно, но чаще отличия замечаются в отстутствии поддержки некоторых библиотек, но это не критично, ибо есть аналоги